# Convert SQL query into CakePHP pagination query

Tags: sql, cakephp, pagination

How can I use the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM `laps`
WHERE `id` = (
  SELECT `id`
  FROM `laps` AS `alt`
  WHERE `alt`.`user_id` = `laps`.`user_id`
  ORDER BY `lap_time` ASC
  LIMIT 1 )
ORDER BY `lap_time` ASC
```

in my CakePHP app and paginate the results?

Answer (score 0):

what you actually want is how to do custom pagination query.
there's some info about that [here](http://book.cakephp.org/view/249/Custom-Query-Pagination)

Answer (score 0):

convert your query to join way, then use cake custom pagination.